# Change module settings stored in an array with drush

Tags: drush

I would like to configure a module ([addtoany](http://drupal.org/project/addtoany)) settings with drush. This is the variable:

```
addtoany_nodetypes: Array
(
    [about_us] => about_us
    [contact] => contact
    [page] => page
    [legal] => 0
    [webform] => 0
)
```

So that, for instance:

```
[page] => page
[legal] => 0
```

becomes

```
[page] => 0
[legal] => legal
```

But I am rather new at drush and I am at a complete loss. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drush does not have any mechanism to convert commandline arguments into php arrays for the variable-set command; however, it is easy to write short php snippets using the php-eval command ('ev' for short).

For example, if you have set up a site alias for your site called "@site":

```
$ drush @site ev 'variable_set("addtoany_nodetypes", array("about_us" => "about_us", "contact" => "contact", "page" => "page", "legal" => 0, "webform" => 0));'
$ drush @site vget addtoany_nodetypes
addtoany_nodetypes: Array
(
    [about_us] => about_us
    [contact] => contact
    [page] => page
    [legal] => 0
    [webform] => 0
)
$ drush @site ev '$v = variable_get("addtoany_nodetypes", array()); $v["page"] = 0; $v["legal"] = "legal"; variable_set("addtoany_nodetypes", $v);'
$ drush @site vget addtoany_nodetypes
addtoany_nodetypes: Array
(
    [about_us] => about_us
    [contact] => contact
    [page] => 0
    [legal] => legal
    [webform] => 0
)
```

If you are not using a site alias, then cd to the Drupal root of your site (or cd to the sites folder that contains settings.php if using a multisite) and remove the "@site" from the examples above.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much @greg_1_anderson !

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the drush help documentation `drush help variable-set` the recommended way to set an array variable is using format=json:

```
php -r "print json_encode(array('drupal', 'simpletest', 'leftandright', 'category'));"  | drush vset --format=json project_dependency_excluded_dependencies -
```

*Don't forget the "**-**" at the end.*